# Template Metaprogramming in loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

Minutes ago, I was pracitise trival algorithm problem. The codes below(concrete logic of the algorithm problem is not importnant, so all we need to know is codes above main function are just TMP):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int digit_in_ones[10] = { 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6 };
constexpr int createOneD(int index);

template<int ...>
struct seq
{

};

template<int A, int ...B>
struct gens : gens<A - 1, A - 1, B...>
{

};

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S ...>
{
    typedef seq<S...> type;
};

template<int N>
class oneDArrayMaker
{
private:
    typedef typename gens<N>::type sequence;
    template<int ...S>
    static constexpr std::array<int, N> make(seq<S ...>)
    {
        return std::array<int, N>{ {createOneD(S)...}};
    }
public:
    static constexpr std::array<int, N> oneDArr = make(sequence());
};
template<int N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> oneDArrayMaker<N>::oneDArr;

constexpr int createOneD(int index)
{
    return index < 10 ? 
        digit_in_ones[index] : 
        digit_in_ones[(index % 100) / 10] + digit_in_ones[index % 10] + 
        (index >= 100 ? digit_in_ones[index / 100] : 0);
}
int main()
{
    int n{}, ans{};
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 800; j++)
        {
            auto temp = oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i] + oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[j] + (i+j < 800 ? oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i+j] : 100) + 4;
            if (temp == n)
            {
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

I knew `loop` and `if`(exclude `constexpr function` and `if constexpr`) are run-time, not compile time. So tricks like `template specialization` are substations for `if` and `loop`. I learned a lesson about silly usage of `if` in template programming from [this article-
Compile Time Loops with C++11 - Creating a Generalized static_for Implementation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857354/Compile-Time-Loops-with-Cplusplus-Creating-a-Gener), here the codes:

```
#include &lt;iostream>
template&lt;int index> void do_stuff()
{
    std::cout &lt;&lt; index &lt;&lt; std::endl;
}
template&lt;int max_index, int index = 0> void stuff_helper()
{
    if (index &lt;= max_index)
    {
        do_stuff&lt;index>();
        stuff_helper&lt;max_index, index + 1>();
    }
}
int main()
{
    stuff_helper&lt;100>();
    return 0;
}
```

author's explanation:

> On the surface, it could look like the if statement would be responsible for terminating the recursion, like how this would work with a "normal" run-time based recursion algorithm. But that's the problem. What works at runtime doesn't work at compile time.
>
> This is an infinite loop, and only stops because compilers limit themselves to a certain recursion depth. In clang, I get an error fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256. You can expect a similar error with your compiler of choice.

**Oops...**, I just state what I have known...

### Finally, it comes to my question:

Now that templates's instantiation(specifically, two-parses) is at compile time. So all templates instantiation in the toppest codes should be at compile time:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 800; j++)
        {
            auto temp = oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i] + ... // 800 * 800 instantiations should be deternimated at compile time
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

As we known
1. the two `for loop` here is runtime ahthough it is out of template function/class's definition and just in main function. 
2. every `auto temp = oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i] + ...` should be initializated at compile time, so 800 * 800 instantiations should be deternimated at compile time.

## Q1: Is runtime loop in main function confliced with 799*799 compile-time template initializations?

My assumption: At compile time, compiler know the depth of the loop, so just unroll the loops, which there is no loop at runtime. 
But I maintain that the two loops(i and j) can also not be deternimated at runtime, I change main function to:

```
int main()
{
    int n{}, ans{}, i{}, j{};
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    std::cout << n << " " << i << " " << j << std::endl;
    for (; i < 800; i++)
    {
        for (; j < 800; j++)
        {
            auto temp = oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i] + oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[j] + (i+j < 800 ? oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i+j] : 100) + 4;
            if (temp == n)
            {
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

Now `i` and `j` have to be deternimated at runtime because of `scanf`. I just pass extra two `0` to stdin.

Here is [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EpCAaA0GEg7suGEe) after alter main function, and output is `12`(the right answer is 128)

It compile successfully and no warning is generated. What confuses me is the output is different from the original codes([live code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gSWCyA5JzI43Nqlg), whose output is `128`(equal to the rigth answer).

After dubug, I find the key is after altering codes,  `for (; i < 800; i++)` is only excuate once `i = 0`, whereas it should have excauted `1~799`, that's the reason for `12`, not `128`.

## Q2: If depth of for loop cannot be deternimated at runtime and TMP codes live in loops, what will happen?

## Q3: How to explain the output `12`

### Update:

Q3 has been resolved by @Scott Brown, I'm so careless.

Q1 and Q2 still confuses me

Comment: You misunderstood what instantiation means. In this particular case, it means to "create" the concrete class/function from the template. No such thing happens at runtime. The loops are irrelevant.

Comment: The "infinite loop" of the recursively instantiated template function exists only because each function instantiated from the function template necessitates another instantiation since the `if`, being a runtime construct, doesn't effect instantiation

Answer (score 2):

You forget to reset j before '`for (; j < 800; j++)`'.

```
int main()
{
    int n{}, ans{}, i{}, j{};
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    std::cout << n << " " << i << " " << j << std::endl;

    int j_orig = j;// here

    for (; i < 800; i++)
    {

        j = j_orig;// and here

        for (; j < 800; j++)
        {
            auto temp = oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i] + oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[j] + (i+j < 800 ? oneDArrayMaker<800>::oneDArr[i+j] : 100) + 4;
            if (temp == n)
            {
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```